# Why is this Firebase Firestore orderBy query not working?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am having issues with the code below, this statement is **not** returning **sorted** docs according to the **sellingPrice**.

```
databaseReference
            .collection("products")
            .where("tags", arrayContains: tag)
            .where("totalUnit", isGreaterThan: 0)
            .orderBy("totalUnit")
            .orderBy("sellingPrice", descending: isDesc)
            .limit(limit)
            .get()
```

Maybe it's the problem with the orderBy("totalUnit") statement because after removing it, the query is returning the docs in **sorted** manner.

---

**I checked, and I think the order is sorted according to totalUnit, but I want the list to be sorted according to the sellingPrice.**

---

And I cannot remove the orderBy("totalUnit") statement, because of the limitations of firestore, I need the statement because of the one above it.

For example, this below isn't exactly what I am getting but it's enough to make you understand the problem I've been facing,

Sample Data -

Products---->

```
Product1 - { "tags" :[a], "totalUnit": 2, "sellingPrice": 1000}
Product2 - { "tags" :[a], "totalUnit": 0, "sellingPrice": 700}
Product3 - { "tags" :[a], "totalUnit": 0, "sellingPrice": 2000}
Product4 - { "tags" :[a], "totalUnit": 3, "sellingPrice": 2000}
Product5 - { "tags" :[a], "totalUnit": 2, "sellingPrice": 500}
```

So that Function should only return,

*If in ascending order - Product5, Product1, Product4*

*If in descending order - Product4, Product1, Product5*

Comment: It's hard to help with "not working". Can you edit your question to include the actual problem you're experiencing, instead of just the code? For example: can you show/print the values that are not in the right order and then show us *that* code and its output?

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I've updated the problem statement and also checked that after removing the two statements related to totalUnit (that weren't that necessary), it managed to solve the problem. But the problem is I don't want to get the data of the product that is out of stock, i.e. totalUnit =0. Kindly help me out.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there any limit to how many queries in a single statement we can make to firebase firestore, like above I've used 2 where, 2 orderBy?

Comment: There are many documented [limits to Firestore queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations). One thing to always check is whether you have an index for the query. If not, the SDK will log a very explicit error message, with a direct link to create the index.

Comment: Yes, I received an error, but then I also created an index for the query. Then there wasn't any error. I was receiving the data, but not in sorted manner.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please help me out, I've updated the question. I checked, and I think the order is sorted according to totalUnit (first orderBy query), but I want the list to be sorted according to the sellingPrice (second orderBy query).

Comment: It seems like you re-asked the question with additional information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897423/how-to-sort-using-multiple-orderby-queries-in-firebase-firestore. In the future, please provide such information in your orignal question (so here) instead of opening a new question for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You used multiple times `order by`. For real-time database, you don't allow to use multiple times `order by`. For more, you go with this link [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) and you can also go with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: But this code works perfectly,                                 databaseReference
            .collection("products")
            .where('totalUnit', isGreaterThan: 0)
            .orderBy("totalUnit")
            .orderBy("sellingPrice", descending: desc)
            .startAfterDocument(lastProduct)
            .limit(limit)
            .get();

Comment: could you get data for both `orderBy` query?

Comment: can you explain @MayurAgarwal

Comment: According to me, here the second orderBy query will work because, the first orderBy statement is just added so that the request to firestore can work properly. If I don't add the first orderBy statement then, I'll get an error.

Comment: yeah got the point and i think first order by is not neccessary

Comment: Yes, it isn't necessary for the sorting but it is necessary due to the firebase rules.

Comment: I understand @MayurAgarwal

Comment: @JahidulIslam This question is about Firestore, while the links you provided are about the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate, and the limit on ordering/filtering you linked does **not** apply to Firestore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen got your point. Thank you for your clarification