# How to sort using multiple orderBy queries in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I want to sort docs according to this scenario -

- Select products which is in stock, (by checking field named "count",
  which specifies the total number of items of a product)
- Sort elements according to another field called "price".

It might seem simple, just use this code -

```
DBRef.collection("col")
  .where("count", isNotEqual: 0)
  .orderBy("price")
  .get();
```

But this will throw an error,
due to the [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) of firebase firestore. So, we'll have to use another orderBy("count") query and also before any other orderBy query.

```
DBRef.collection("col")
  .where("count", isNotEqual: 0)
  .orderBy("count")
  .orderBy("price")
  .get();
```

And that'll sort the docs according to the `count` field, and not according to the price field. How can I sort docs list according to the `price` field at the same time.

I even tried a *work around*,

```
 databaseReference
            .collection("products")
            .where("tags", arrayContains: tag)
            .where("sellingPrice", isGreaterThan: 0)
            .orderBy("sellingPrice", descending: isDesc)
            .where("totalUnit", isGreaterThan: 0)
            .orderBy("totalUnit")
            .limit(limit)
            .get()
```

I added another where statement for the "sellingPrice" field, so that I would have to add orderBy("sellingPrce") the first orderBy statement.
But I'm still getting the error

> Failed assertion: line 421 pos 16: 'field == orders[0][0]': The
> initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([sellingPrice]), false]][0][0]'
> has to be the same as the where() field parameter
> 'FieldPath([totalUnit])' when an inequality operator is invoked.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of your second query will be sorted by count first, and then by price. There is no way to get them from the database without first sorting on count, so you will have to reorder them in your application code.

What you *could* consider is not giving the documents where the count is equal to `0` a `count` field at all. This will result at them being excluded from the index, and that also means you can put the `orderBy("count")` at the end of the query.

Alternatively, you can add a `isInStock` type field that you update in sync with the `count` field. Once you do that, you can do an equality condition (`where("isInStock", "==", true)`), which doesn't require an `orderBy` clause.

Comment: I added another where statement, so that I would have to place orderBy("sellingPrice") as the first orderBy statement according to the firestore limitations, but it didn't work. I've updated the question, can you please check that out.

Comment: You can only have range conditions (like `isGreaterThan`) on a single field in Firestore, so your workaround won't work. In fact, it's precisely why I added a `isInStock` field in my answer, so that you can do an equality check, which doesn't require an `orderBy` call on the field.