# Multiple query on firebase documents in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get docs in a specific range using the "level" field(e.g.: between level 5 and level 20). And then sort these docs by specific field(e.g.: price). so the "level" field only prepares the range of these docs that users want. And the other query specifies the order of documents the user requests. But i can't make it that i want. Because my codes order the docs with "level" range and ignore other query.

I want this:

```
Level 7 - 1234567 USD
level 14 - 12345 USD
level 5 - 1234 USD
```

But my code running like this:

```
Level 5 - 123 USD
level 6 - 12 USD
level 7 - 12345 USD
level 8 - 1234 USD
```

Here is my code:

```
query = query
        .where("level", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 5)
        .where("level", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 15)
        .orderBy("level", descending: false) // <-- if i remove this, i got error
        .orderBy("price", descending: true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a range condition on `level`, you will first need to order on that field. That also means that results will be returned by order of `level` first, and only on any other field you order on for documents that have the same `level` value.

There is no way to change this behavior within Firestore, so you will have to re-sort the results in your application code.

Also see:

- [How to sort using multiple orderBy queries in Firebase Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897423/how-to-sort-using-multiple-orderby-queries-in-firebase-firestore)
- [Use multiple orderBy in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73528458/use-multiple-orderby-in-firebase)

Comment: Okay so, why? Why doesn't Google implement such a simple and useful mechanism?

Comment: Whenever Firestore doesn't implement a query feature that you consider simple, it is usually because it wouldn't be able to meet its performance guarantees at scale with that feature. If this query feature is crucial to your app, consider using a database that *does* implement the feature - but likely you'll lose the performance/scalability guarantee that Firestore offers. You'll have to make your own trade-off which one is more important to you in that case.