# firestore collection data order by date

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to order by date the data coming from firestore database  that is given to it in milliseconds but when i use .orderBy('date', descending: true) in my code nothing appears in my application and when i remove it everything goes fine.it gives me empty list

```
    class FirebaseManager {
  static bool existEmail = false;
  static bool weakPassword = false;
  static CollectionReference<TaskModel> getTasksCollection() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Tasks")
        .withConverter<TaskModel>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
        return TaskModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!);
      },
      toFirestore: (task, _) {
        return task.toJson();
      },
    );
  }
 static Stream<QuerySnapshot<TaskModel>> getTasks(DateTime date) {
    return getTasksCollection()
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .where("userId", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
        .where("date",
            isEqualTo: DateUtils.dateOnly(date).millisecondsSinceEpoch)
        .snapshots();
  }

}
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<TaskModel>>(
            stream: FirebaseManager.getTasks(selectedDate),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                const Center(child: Text("something went wrong"));
              }
              List<TaskModel> tasks =
                  snapshot.data?.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList() ?? [];
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return TasksItem(tasks[index]);
                  },
```

oredering data from firestore and it returns empyty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an order-by clause to the query, it sounds like Firestore requires a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) and you haven't defined that index.

It sounds like you're missing the necessary index, which you have to [create yourself](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). You can either catch the error that Firestore throws for this and click the link in there, or you can go to the Firestore console and create the index from scratch there,

Also see:

- [Multiple query on firebase documents in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77232086/multiple-query-on-firebase-documents-in-flutter/77232167#77232167)
- [Use multiple orderBy in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73528458/use-multiple-orderby-in-firebase)